# Error Launching Presto Server while trying to access Hive

Tags: presto

I am trying to Launch Presto to query Hive ON RHEL Machine.

But while Launching the Presto Server via `"./launcher run"`, i am getting the following error :

```
3 errors
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'http-server.http.port=8080 ' was not used
  at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:235)

2) Error: Could not coerce value '8080 ' to int (property 'http-server.http.port') in order to call [public io.airlift.http.server.HttpServerConfig io.airlift.http.server.HttpServerConfig.setHttpPort(int)]
  at io.airlift.http.server.HttpServerModule.configure(HttpServerModule.java:74)

3) Error: Invalid configuration property node.id: is malformed (for class io.airlift.node.NodeConfig.nodeId)
  at io.airlift.node.NodeModule.configure(NodeModule.java:34)

3 errors
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:242)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:116)
        at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:67)
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things. You need to remove the space after "http-server.http.port=8080".

Also, your node.id property is invalid. The node.id should match the following regex: "[A-Za-z0-9][_A-Za-z0-9-]*" (see https://github.com/airlift/airlift/blob/1e5694fb13ac6ca9cbdae1a1e60909c62fc7a64e/node/src/main/java/io/airlift/node/NodeConfig.java#L30).

Answer (score 0):

same question:  No factory for connector jmx

remove all  /etc/*  config files space