# Error Launching Presto Server while running the Presto Launcher

Tags: java, presto, launcher

I am trying to Launch Presto using the launcher ON Centos.

But while Launching the Presto Server via "./launcher run", i am getting the following error :

```
2023-05-16T18:26:43.992+0800    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error: Could not coerce value '8080 ' to int (property 'http-server.http.port') in order to call [public com.facebook.airlift.http.server.HttpServerConfig com.facebook.airlift.http.server.HttpServerConfig.setHttpPort(int)]

2) Configuration property 'discovery-server.enabled' was not used
  at com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:244)

3) Configuration property 'http-server.http.port' was not used
  at com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:244)
```

Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968787/error-launching-presto-server-while-trying-to-access-hive), I have removed the space after "http-server.http.port=8080", and put the node.id as 1.

However, the issue remains. What should I do to fix this issue?

Additional CONFIG FILE information:

1. In **catalog/jmx.properties**

   connector.name=jmx
2. In **config.properties**

   coordinator=true
   node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
   http-server.http.port=8080
   query.max-memory=5GB
   query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
   discovery-server.enabled=true
   discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080